# Config Navigation bar only work if viewControllers are created inside viewWillAppear in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with 2 `ViewControllers`: `HomeViewController` and `ProfileViewController`

Inside `HomeViewController`, I have to change the `NavigationBar` appearance with the following code:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let nav = self.navigationController {
            nav.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 0
        }
        let logo = UIImage(named: "plentinaText")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 0))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo)
        
        imageView.tintColor = .white
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        container.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width)
        ])
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView = container
    }
```

Problem is, this block of code only work if I create `HomeViewController` `ProfileViewController` inside `viewWillAppear` in `UITabBarController`.

If I put it in `ViewDidLoad`, it don't even have a `NavigationBar`. But when I push to another vc and go back to `HomeViewController`, the Nav bar will work as I wanted.

```
//
//  HomeTabbarController.swift
//  Plentina
//
//  Created on 10/29/21.
//

import UIKit

class HomeTabbarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = PlenitaColors.buttonBackGround // your color
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.systemGray4
        } else {
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
           let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
           appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = PlenitaColors.buttonBackGround
           
            tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // tabbar 1
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Custom", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photo") as? HomeViewController
        let item1 = viewController
        let unselectedIcon1 = UIImage(named: "tabbarHome")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let selectedIcon1 = UIImage(named: "tabbarHome")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let icon1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Loans", image: unselectedIcon1, selectedImage: selectedIcon1)
        item1!.tabBarItem = icon1
        // tabbar 2
        let unselectedIcon2 = UIImage(named: "tabbarProfile")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let selectedIcon2 = UIImage(named: "tabbarProfile")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let item2 = ProfileViewController()
        let icon2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: unselectedIcon2, selectedImage: selectedIcon2)
        item2.tabBarItem = icon2

        let controllers = [item1!, item2]  // array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface
        self.viewControllers = controllers
    }

    // Delegate methods
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        print("Should select viewController: \(viewController.title ?? "") ?")
        return true
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I just need to leave `self.viewControllers = controllers` in `viewWillAppear` and move the rest to `ViewDidLoad`, but I still don't know why?

```
class HomeTabbarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var controllers: [Any]?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = PlenitaColors.buttonBackGround // your color
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.systemGray4
        } else {
            UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
           let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
           appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = PlenitaColors.buttonBackGround
           
            tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }

        // tabbar 1
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Custom", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photo") as? HomeViewController
        let item1 = viewController
        let unselectedIcon1 = UIImage(named: "tabbarHome")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let selectedIcon1 = UIImage(named: "tabbarHome")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let icon1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Loans", image: unselectedIcon1, selectedImage: selectedIcon1)
        item1!.tabBarItem = icon1
        // tabbar 2
        let unselectedIcon2 = UIImage(named: "tabbarProfile")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let selectedIcon2 = UIImage(named: "tabbarProfile")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let item2 = ProfileViewController()
        let icon2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: unselectedIcon2, selectedImage: selectedIcon2)
        item2.tabBarItem = icon2

        controllers = [item1!, item2]  // array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.viewControllers = controllers as? [UIViewController]

    }

    // Delegate methods
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        print("Should select viewController: \(viewController.title ?? "") ?")
        return true
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```